# Not able to make the navbar items dynamic in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have navbar component which I have placed in an application.hbs so that it should be visible always.But I want to change the title of the navbar with each page I visit ( say I am on index page it should say "Home" , if I am on profile page it should say profile,etc).Right now what is happening is navbar title always remains "Home" for all the page.This is happening because the navbar gets rendered onlu during the time it loads  the page in browser and after that it doesn't change according to page.

application.hbs

```
{{top-navbar dp_url=model.profile.dp_url first_name=model.profile.first_name title=title}}

{{outlet}}
```

Here the I am computing the value of title depending upon which page the user is.

application.js(controller)

```
if (currentPage === "" || currentPage === "#"){
      currentState.set('title',"Home")
 }
else if(currentPage === "Userprofile"){
      console.log('myStudio');
      currentState.set('title',"UserProfile");
}
```

In here the `currentpage` has the current url of app and I am comparing it and deciding the value of title for navbar.

But the top-navbar title value gets calculated only for the first time when user load the app in browser and not when I move ffrom one route to another.

I have also tried the `Ember.Evented` but not able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Ember.js and Ember-data version are you using, `currentState` is [deprecated since 2.1](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v2.x/#toc_ember-component-currentstate), anyway looks like you're using a private method intended for Ember internals and not meant to be used in an application.

A possible (but maybe unnecessary complicated) way to accomplish what you want is:

1. Create a model with the information you want to mutate in the navbar (e.g. `navbar-data`).
2. In the route where the navbar is rendered, create and return a record for it using a fixed numeric ID (e.g. `store.createRecord('navbar-data', { id: 1, title: "index" })`).
3. Pass the created record to the component (instead of just a string).
4. Whenever you want to change, peek the record with `store.peekRecord('navbar-data', 1)` and change the value you want to change in the navbar.

Of course, the record you use for that must **not** be saved with `record.save()`.